# Getting the maximum value from a query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to find the most common customer First Name of all customers whose home address is in Australia using the `AdventureWorks` Database (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms124438(v=sql.100).aspx).

The code I have below gives me the answer i need ("Lacey" used 25 times) but it results in 561 rows. How can I limit this to 1 row **without** using `TOP x` or `SET ROWCOUNT` to manipulate results?

```
SELECT 
    FirstName, 
    COUNT(PP.FirstName) AS FirstNameCount
FROM
    Person.Person AS PP
    INNER JOIN Sales.Customer AS SC 
        ON SC.PersonID = PP.BusinessEntityID
    INNER JOIN Person.BusinessEntity AS PBE
        ON PBE.BusinessEntityID = PP.BusinessEntityID 
    INNER JOIN Person.BusinessEntityAddress AS PBEA
        ON PBEA.BusinessEntityID = PBE.BusinessEntityID
    INNER JOIN Person.AddressType AS PAT
        ON PAT.AddressTypeID = PBEA.AddressTypeID
    INNER JOIN Person.Address AS PA 
        ON PA.AddressID = PBEA.AddressID
WHERE
    PAT.AddressTypeID = 2 AND 
    StateProvinceID = 50 OR 
    StateProvinceID = 64 OR 
    StateProvinceID = 66 OR 
    StateProvinceID = 71 OR 
    StateProvinceID = 77
GROUP BY 
    FirstName
ORDER BY 
    FirstNameCount DESC
```

Comment: Just curious - why can't you use `TOP`? This is specifically what `TOP` is designed to do - limit the result to X number of rows.

Comment: Because the questioner wont allow me to

Comment: You are mixing ands and ors, see [operator precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx). Either use `in` to list StateProvinceIDs or put parentheses around it.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following at the end of the query:

```
-- << the query you have here
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in the WHERE clause.

If you add parentheses you should get a better result set ie.

```
WHERE
PAT.AddressTypeID = 2 AND 
(StateProvinceID = 50 OR 
StateProvinceID = 64 OR 
StateProvinceID = 66 OR 
StateProvinceID = 71 OR 
StateProvinceID = 77)
```

or even better would be to use in ie

```
WHERE PAT.AddressTypeID = 2 AND StateProvinceID IN (50,64,66,71,77)
```

and I think the limit of only showing the first line may be achievable using something like MAX(COUNT(*))